# How to connect to a machine which is sitting behind NAT router?

Tags: ip, tcp, network, nat

I have a server that needs to push a message to a client from which it received a request a few days ago. Now request which was received has the IP address of the NAT router behind which the client sits.

I was wondering if I could somehow push a message to a client (or somehow make a TCP connection) who doesn't have a public IP and is sitting behind a NAT router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Not unless you know the current public IP address of the destination's router *and* the router forwards the required transport-layer port (aka destination NAT or reverse NAT).

A very frequently used approach for this problem is that the client keeps polling the server.